# Spring Cloud Gateway Not Forwarding Requests To HTTPS When Using Eureka Load Balancer

Tags: ssl, https, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-gateway

I am working with microservices routing with `Spring Cloud Gateway` and registered in `Eureka Server`.

The microservices are running in multiple instances that's why I need to use Load Balancer in the gateway as below

```
spring:
  application:
    name: GATEWAY-NAME
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        wiretap: true
      httpserver:
        wiretap: true
      routes:
        - id: MICROSERVICE-NAME
          uri: lb://MICROSERVICE-NAME
          predicates:
            - Path=/path/**
```

This is working fine when the microservices are running on HTTP protocol without SSL. But when I enable SSL in the microservice servers, the upper configuration doesn't work. Rather it works when I use the URL directly instead of load balancer as below.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: GATEWAY-NAME
  cloud:
    gateway:
      httpclient:
        wiretap: true
      httpserver:
        wiretap: true
      routes:
        - id: MICROSERVICE-NAME
          uri: https://domain:port
          predicates:
            - Path=/path/**
```

Now I need to use the load balancer when SSL is enabled in the servers where microservices are running. I also tried `uri: lbs://MICROSERVICE-NAME` but didn't get any result.

How can I achieve my goal? Please let me know what should I do to redirect to HTTPS using the load balancer from gateway route.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the foll to the client/microservice application worked

--eureka.instance.securePortEnabled=true

No change required to lbs://.
Apparently we need either of the two (eureka arg OR lbs://)

See spencergibb ans [Spring Cloud Gateway and Eureka working in SSL with microservices defaulting to HTTP, but should be HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61238132/spring-cloud-gateway-and-eureka-working-in-ssl-with-microservices-defaulting-to)

However, lbs:// did not work for me, the eureka arg did work!